# Using a Mix Shader to blend 2 Principled BSDF (CYCLES)

Tags: texturing, vertex-colors

Hey Blender Community,

I am having a recurring problem when trying to blend 2 Quixel Megascans together using the mix shader and vertex colour. Both materials work great on their own but when trying to mix it makes the second material turn pink, like it would if there was a missing link (there are no missing links).

I will show both materials separately below along with the issue im having when using the mix shader.

First material - Grass:
[image]

Second Material - Tyre Tracks:
[image]

Combined Materials - Material Preview:
[image]

Combined Material - Rendered View (CYCLES):
[image]

Combined Material with Vertex Colour - Rendered View (CYCLES):
[image]
[image]

Comment: You are most likely either exceeding either available video memory or Blender software limits

Comment: Ah okay yeah i think that might be it because i use a relatively old laptop with the CPU instead of GPU. I was getting very confused because in all the other tutorials it would work perfectly. Thank you.